# hyperscan __aligned_malloc issue in windows

Tags: c++11, d, dmd

I am trying to build and use the hyperscan on Windows. When i executed `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"  ..\`
i could see the message

```
-- Looking for posix_memalign
-- Looking for posix_memalign - not found
-- Looking for _aligned_malloc
-- Looking for _aligned_malloc - found
```

and able to build the hyperscan as well. However when i try to use the hs.lib in my program ( i am using a d lang based program) and compile it using `dmd` i am getting below error

```
hs.lib(alloc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__aligned_malloc referenced in function
     "void * __vectorcall ue2::aligned_malloc_internal(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64)" 
(?aligned_malloc_internal@ue2@@YQPEAX_K0@Z)
```

from the error it says __aligned_malloc not found however while generating using cmake it says __aligned_malloc is found.

Can you please help me ? i am not sure what went wrong.

Comment: This looks like a missing symbol referred to by your library. It does not say that `__aligned_malloc` is not found, it says that `__imp__aligned_malloc` is not found. dmd needs to be told the correct library to contain this function. What I can possibly think of is that you are building your lib against one version of MSVC libc, but linking against a different version with dmd.